# How to convert bidi string into visual order wstring?

Tags: c++, boost, byte-order-mark, wstring, bidi

for example I have this string:

```
std::wstring s = L"123";
s.push_back(0x202e);
s.append(L"abc");
```

Here `0x202e` is UTF-16 mark RLO (Right-to-Left override). Because of this, string after printing looks: `cba123`. I want to ask if there is any function which could convert first string into the one which is printed.

Also it would be good if that function also could handle all kind of UTF-16 BOMs.

Is there any standart way? I'm coding with C++ and I'm free to use boost or some other free lib.

Comment: http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/bidi

Comment: `wstring` is OS- and compiler- dependent and portable code cannot assume any particular encoding.

Comment: @n.m. I gave an example of situation what may be. There a few ways to get such string.

Comment: I objected to your mixing of the notions of UTF and wstring, which is not portable. If you want to convert a bidi string to the visual order, you need to apply the bidi algorithm outlined [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/). A free implementation can be found [here](http://www.fribidi.org/).